# Asymptotic expression of the maximum of the relative error of the Fourier expansion of the multifactorial

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, asymptotics, fourier-series, gamma-function

I wanted to study the following problem:

Let

$$x!_{(a)}=a^{\frac{x}{a}}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}$$

where

$$C_{a}(x)=\frac{1}{a}\left(1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor\frac{a-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{a}x\right)+\operatorname{mod}\left(a-1,2\right)\cos\left(\pi x\right)\right)$$

The analitic continuation of the multifactorial.

> An alternative representation of $C_a(x)$ is:
> $$C_a(x)=\frac{1}{a}\sum_{k=1}^{a}\cos\left(\theta_k x\right)\qquad \text{where }\theta_k=\arccos\left(\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}{a}\right)\right)\neq \frac{2k\pi}{a}\text{ for }k\in[1,...,a]$$

And let

$$x?_{(a)}=a^{\frac{x}{a}}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_{a}(x-j)$$

The Fourier expansion of $x!_{(a)}$

---

**I want to calculate the maximum relative error of $x?_{(a)}$ compared to $x!_{(a)}$**

$\text{rel.err.}(x)=\left|\dfrac{x?_{(a)}-x!_{(a)}}{x!_{(a)}}\right|$

To calculate the maximum therefore I have to take the derivative and set it equal to $0$ (to simplify the calculations I remove the absolute value)

> $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{x?_{(a)}-x!_{(a)}}{x!_{(a)}}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{x?_{(a)}}{x!_{(a)}}$
> $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{x?_{(a)}-x!_{(a)}}{x!_{(a)}}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{\displaystyle a^{\frac{x}{a}}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_a\left(x-j\right)}{\displaystyle a^{\frac{x}{a}}\Gamma\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)\prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}}$
> $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{x?_{(a)}-x!_{(a)}}{x!_{(a)}}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_a\left(x-j\right)}{\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}}$

$$\color{blue}{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\dfrac{\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_a\left(x-j\right)}{\displaystyle \prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}}=0}$$

> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0\;\Leftrightarrow\; f'(x)g(x)=f(x)g'(x)$$
> $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{f_i(x)}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}a_i^{f_i(x)}\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(a_i)f_i'(x)\right)$$
> ${\displaystyle\left[\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_{a}'\left(x-j\right)\right]\cdot\left[ \prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}\right]=\left[\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_{a}'\left(x-j\right)\right]\cdot \left[ \prod_{j=1}^{a-1}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right)^{C_{a}\left(x-j\right)}\right]\cdot \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\ln\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right) C'_{a}\left(x-j\right)\right]}$

$$\color{blue}{{\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_{a}'\left(x-j\right)=\left[\sum_{j=1}^{a}\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}C_{a}\left(x-j\right)\right]\cdot \left[ \sum_{j=1}^{a-1}\ln\left(\frac{a^{\frac{a-j}{a}}}{\Gamma\left(\frac{j}{a}\right)}\right) C'_{a}\left(x-j\right)\right]}}$$

This equation is a goniometric equation, in fact it depends only on $C_a(x)$ (which is the sum of goniometric functions) and its derivative. But I got stuck at this step.

---

I think this problem is very interesting for 3 reasons:

1. The Fourier expansion of the multifactorial is a finite sum and not a series, therefore the maximum of the relative error it is a fixed value, once $a$ is chosen.
2. The equation to find the maximum relative error is a goniometric equation, therefore it follows a periodic trend and remains limited as $x$ increases.
3. By representing the trend of the maximum relative error, we see that in addition to being very small, it has a less than logarithmic trend.

So I would like to see what happens as $a$ increases (if it grows unlimitedly or converges to some value)

Here is a table of the values ​​I found:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline
a&\text{max. rel. err.}\\\hline
1&=0.000\%\\
2&\approx 0.639\%\\
3&\approx 1.530\%\\
4&\approx 1.814\%\\
5&\approx 2.056\%\\
6&\approx 2.225\%\\
7&\approx 2.350\%\\
8&\approx 2.465\%\\
9&\approx 2.546\%\\
10&\approx 2.630\%\\
11&\approx 2.688\%\\
12&\approx 2.752\%\\
13&\approx 2.796\%\\
14&\approx 2.848\%\\
15&\approx 2.883\%\\
16&\approx 2.925\%\\
17&\approx 2.954\%\\
18&\approx 2.989\%\\
19&\approx 3.013\%\\
20&\approx 3.043\%\\
...&...\\
100&\approx 3.562\%\\
200&\approx 3.663\%\\
500&\approx 3.736\%\\
1000&\approx 3.766\%\\\hline
\end{array}$$

[image: Here the graphic representation]

---

**Edit**

I think it's useful that:
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}C_a(x)=\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$